# Display PDF in browser instead of downloading from URL

Tags: typescript, angular6, pdfview

Using Angular 6, I am making a API call to get the path of the pdf file in S3 bucket. Using this i need to display the PDF. But instead it is downloading the PDF to local client machine.

Currently i am appending the url returned by the API to an iframe.

```
public showPDFPreviewModal(pdfSrcUrl){
    this.display = 'block';
    $('#pdfView').attr('src',pdfSrcUrl);
  };

    <iframe  id="pdfView" width="1100" height="500"> </iframe>
```

How can i preview the pdf without downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use object tag to show PDF document on web page like below.

`<object width="610" height="740" data="...PDF file url.."></object>`

For more information check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp.

Hope it helps.